# How to noindex automatically all post of a specific category?

Tags: noindex

My site is auto importing feed of other website. Obviously it's copied content for google. So i want to noindex all posts comes from that feed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Being `excluded-cat` and `excluded-cat-1` the categories you want to exclude from indexing:

```
add_action('wp_head','AS_exclude_category_from_indexing');

function AS_exclude_category_from_indexing(){
  $html="";
  if(has_category('excluded-cat') || has_category('excluded-cat-1')){
    $html= "<meta name=\"robots\" content=\"noindex,follow\">".PHP_EOL;
  } 
  echo $html;
}
```

Comment: thank you for you reply i found this code and worked -     /* Noindex all posts in a category */
add_filter("wpseo_robots", function($robots) {
  if (is_single() && in_category(array(10588, 13416))) {
    return "noindex,follow";
  }
  return $robots;
});

Comment: `wpseo_robots` is not a  native WP filter, I guess is Wp Yoast, in case you do't use that plugin this filter won't work

Comment: yes i'm using yoast plugin.